# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3002

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run a very simple node file that used to work, but now I get this error.

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3002
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1081:14)
```

The thing is that if I run another application in this port, there's no problem. Even If I change the port in the file, the error persists.

The code of the file:

```
var http = require('http');

var opcoes = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 3002,
    path: '/',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
}

//Content-type
var html = 'nome=José'; //x-www-form-urlencoded
var json = { nome: 'José' };
var string_json = JSON.stringify(json);

var buffer_corpo_response = [];

var req = http.request(opcoes, function(res) {

    res.on('data', function(pedaco) {
        buffer_corpo_response.push(pedaco);
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        var corpo_responde = Buffer.concat(buffer_corpo_response).toString();
        console.log(corpo_responde);
    });
});

req.write(string_json);
req.end();
```

Comment: Is this error ocurring on your local machine?

Comment: yes, it is running on my local machine

Comment: Does the app you are querying is running and listen on this port? Or does localhost:3002 require an authentication ?

Comment: it just running and listen. It does not require any authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your port in your code is `3005`. Make sure they all share that number.

Comment: sorry, I edited the text. It doesn't work in any port.

Answer (score 0):

I stumble into this question and realized that my particular case might be related to future people asking for answers:

1. I had a server app running in WSL (Ubuntu)
2. I was trying to connect another server app to 1 in Windows Terminal
3. I was getting the `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3002` in the Windows Terminal app but I was able to call the WSL (Ubuntu) from the browser and Postman

I decided to run both in WSL (Ubuntu). It works now